# Swift 3 extract group from Regex - NS-bridging mess

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to do a simple Regex in Swift 3, extracting a number from the input string.

As I am not familiar with iOS it's proven to be quite a challenge. I highly suspect that my error lies in using both `String` and `NSString` simultaneously.

```
let url = "a5b"
let nsUrl = url as NSString

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "a(\\d)b", options: [])
let matches = regex.matches(in: url, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: url.characters.count))

somestuff(str: nsUrl.substring(with: matches[1].range))
```

Fails with the following exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

What is the correct way to match and get the number?

Comment: This may not be critical in your example data, but `url.characters.count` needs to be changed to `url.utf16.count`. `NSRegularExpression` uses UTF-16 based location and length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes are zero-based but the captured group is at range index 1

```
somestuff(str: nsUrl.substring(with: matches[0].rangeAt(1)))
```

You should test for no matches anyway...

---

About the return value of `matches(in`:

> An array of `NSTextCheckingResult` objects. Each result gives the overall matched range via its `range` property, and the range of each individual capture group via its `rangeAt(_:)` method. The range `{NSNotFound, 0}` is returned if one of the capture groups did not participate in this particular match.

Note: `range` is actually the same as `rangeAt(0)`

Comment: matches[0] gives me a5b (the entire input), the same as in Java.

Comment: Thank you, this works, will accept as soon as possible. Would you mind going into a little detail why this is necessary? I do not really understand the API. It gives you an array of matches, logically one would expect to find the capture group at matches[1]. Why `rangeAt` that "returns the result type that the range represents" gives you the range of the capture group is beyond my understanding.

Comment: @Zackline: If your input string is `"a5b c6d"` then `matches[0]` refers to the first match "a5d" and `matches[1]` to the second match "c6d". Within each match, `.rangeAt(1)` refers to the first capture group.

Comment: Thank you all, I understand. I still don't understand the documentation on `rangeAt` though. If it was called `group` I would immediately know what it does. Looking at `rangeAt` I discarded it after reading `returns the result type that the range represents`. Where does it return any type? Should the documentation not be something among the likes of `returns the range at the given index`?